# Anger vs. Wrath

Tags: meaning, differences

Could you, please, explain the difference between the words 'anger' and 'wrath'?

Merriam & Webster says

> **anger**
>   <sub><sub>transitive verb</sub></sub>
>   to make angry: *he was angered by the decision*
>   <sub><sub>intransitive verb</sub></sub>
>   to become angry
>
> **wrath**
>    1. strong vengeful anger or indignation
>    2. retributory punishment for an offense or a crime :  divine chastisement

It seems to me that the latter has rather positive aspect than negative.

Comment: Hello, 151. What do dictionaries say?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Webster's dictionary gives us a detailed definition of 'anger' and about 'wrath' it merely says that it is 'extreme anger'. But it hardly helps, honestly.

Comment: It would help me. What you may not find in a dictionary is that 'wrath' tends to be used more for dramatic effect, and isn't the colloquial choice.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I guess, 'wrath' is not used very often.

Comment: It would not be my choice in conversation. But Steinbeck, Tolkien, and the Bible translators use it well.

Comment: Wrath has a big connotation of someone with superior strength actively channelling their anger into something destructive. Mainly used in such places as the old testament to tell about consequences of angering the deity. Same for the word _Ire_

Comment: If you look up [*wrath* in Merriam-Webster](http://beta.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wrath) and scroll down you'll find a brief discussion of wrath, anger, fury, indignation, etc..

Comment: The "anger" reference added to the question is not relevant. What's relevant is the noun "anger" not the verb "anger".

Comment: For natural calamities, 'nature's wrath' is often used by print media, the context being, nature's wrath against man's attack on her.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=wrath) provides a good definition of **wrath** that aligns well with some of the comments above:

> 1. **Forceful**, often **vindictive anger**.

Example:

> *He feared the wrath of his employer.*

**Wrath** can also mean:

> 2. **Punishment or vengeance** as a manifestation of anger.

Example:

> *He decided to risk the wrath of the authorities and go ahead with the plan.*

In a religious context, **wrath** can also have a more specific meaning of  **divine retribution for wrongdoing or sin**.

Example:

> *You broke the divine law by murdering your brother and must suffer the wrath of the Almighty.*

Some sources note that **wrath** can imply **righteous anger** (similar to the above):

> **righteous indignation and condemnation** especially of a deity or sovereign

(Webster's Unabridged)

It can also be used humorously in certain contexts:

> **wrath:** extreme anger (chiefly used for **humorous or rhetorical effect**)

([Oxford American Dictionary](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/wrath))

Comment: @user151486 By the way, *wrath* can indeed have a more positive connotation when it means **righteous indignation**, especially on the part of a deity such as a holy God. That's the implication of *wrath* in the Bible and the Qur'an, for example.

Comment: And they don't usually say 'righteous anger', do they?

Comment: On the contrary, "righteous anger" is quite a frequent collocation. But you can use a single word like "wrath" instead, in appropriate contexts.

Comment: @user151486 No problem!

Answer (score 1):

The old word wrath is a literary variant for extreme anger. The normal word in spoken language is anger or, if stronger, fury. oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/wrath?q=wrath

Answer (score 0):

Anger (according to Websters) is "a strong feeling of displeasure and usually of antagonism".

Wrath is "strong vengeful anger or indignation" or "retributory punishment for an offence or crime: divine chastisement".

So, wrath has connotations of power and control whereas anger doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

The interesting difference is, **wrath** involves *action*. Usually action with an energy of violence, vengeance or punishment. **Anger** is often expected, understandable, even if frightening, anger is normally a result of an *activating event*. Once it escalates from feeling to action, anger becomes wrath.

Comment: AP's answer has said this (forceful anger / often vindictive ... may involve retribution / punishment). And AP has added the references, attributions and links expected on ELU.